# What are the html5lib system requirements?

Tags: python, html5lib

I have been reading the [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) docs but I just can't find anything about requirements. Can it be run in a python only environment, or does it require C libraries (like the Lxml parser).

Does it run on Python 3 or does it require 2.x, like Beautiful Soup?

Comment: The repo you link to has both python and python3 directories, the README says it's pure python, and setup.py doesn't list any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It has some external Python dependencies but it does not requires any C libraries.